# How to use a variable declared in C within inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, keyboardinterrupt

I am trying to figure out how to use the variable ret within the inline assembly code below, but I keep getting this error: undefined reference to 'ret.

```
char getkey(void){
int ret;
asm(
"movq $0, %RAX\n\t"
"INT $0X16\n\t"
"movq %RAX, ret"
);
return ret;
}
```

Comment: I am using gcc. I am using ubuntu OS.

Comment: You should look at assembler templates and passing the variables as input (and output parameters) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: I've added a link to the docs in my first comment.

Comment: `ret` is the name of an instruction; this may be what is causing it to fail

Comment: I changed the name of ret and it still does not work.

Comment: Aside from the fact you're not using GCC's inline assembly correctly, this code can never work. The INT 0x16 keyboard BIOS interface only works in real mode and you can't access the 64-bit registers (eg. RAX) from real mode. (Theoretically it could work under a 64-bit DOS extender, but as far I know no such thing exists.)

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do won't work. PC BIOS interrupts, like int 16h, are only available when the system is running in real mode (i.e, at startup before the MMU is enabled); they cannot be used in Linux executables.

That being said, in general, you can specify an output register using [gcc assembler constraints](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html). For example:

```
asm(
    "movq $0, %RAX\n"
    "int $0x16\n"
    : "=a" (ret)
);
```

Note that there's no `mov` instruction at the end of this code! The `"=A"` constraint tells the compiler that the result will be left in the A register; it'll figure out what to do from there. (There are ways to eliminate the first `mov` as well, if you're clever about it.)

Comment: So you are saying my code and even the code you provided will not work because I cannot use the interrupts?

Comment: @stingraing Correct. You can't use BIOS interrupts in any operating system newer than MS-DOS.

Comment: So how can I access the bios. How do the OS do it? If I created an OS, wouldn't the OS be able to? Is this not how they create libraries for programming languages?

Comment: @stingraing You can't, and it doesn't. Modern operating systems basically ignore the BIOS beyond startup and interface with the hardware directly.

Comment: How can I interface with the hardware?

Comment: On Linux you interface with the hardware mostly via kernel resident code, mostly in device drivers. Device drivers *can* present a usually restricted interface to the `userland` via device nodes in the filesystem, via `ioctl()`. Sometimes the address space for registers of a device can also be mapped directly to `userspace` to implement essentially `userspace` drivers.

Comment: If you start the pc and you have not downloaded any drivers, how does the OS know how to use a device?

Comment: Well, actually there *is* a mov in this code, just not after the interrupt call.  So how about `asm("int $0x16" : "=A" (ret) : "0" (0));`?

Comment: @stingraing When you start an IBM-PC(assume a legacy BIOS), the BIOS contains interrupts that can handle the basic hardware. Many people start out by making calls to the BIOS for their first toy OS/bootloader. Unfortunately if you use protected mode most BIOSes don't support protected mode calls. Usually protected mode OSes implement drivers that communicate with the hardware that is discovered. This is usually done by communicating with IO ports (in/out family of instructions) or reading/writing directly to memory. Essentially rolling your own device drivers that a BIOS interrupt did for you

Comment: The `"A"` constraint actually specifies the EDX:EAX register pair as a 64-bit value (only usable in 32 bit mode).  You want the `"a"` constraint for rax/eax/ax by itself.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Good catch. I was cribbing from some code I'd written that called `rdtsc`.